# Display field content inside a matrix from a different locale

Tags: matrix, localization

I am building a site with 2 different languages - English and Chinese. Is it possible to retrieve only one field inside a matrix in English while I am in Chinese site? But the rest of the matrix fields, I want them to be kept in Chinese.

Below is an example snippet from retrieving the field inside the matrix. Is it possible to force translate it directly to English regardless of the current locale the site is in?

```
{{ globalMatrixTable.globalPresenceItem }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [query a global set in a different site](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/globals.html#querying-globals):

```
{% set englishMatrixTable = craft.globalSets()
    .handle('globalMatrixTable')
    .site('yourEnglishSiteHandle')
    .one() %}

{{ englishMatrixTable.globalPresenceItem }}
```